# create pdf to docx file using PHPword

Tags: php, pdf, xmlwriter, phpword

I am using  for creating a .docx file PHP word, I have one pdf file .its creating .docx file but when I tried to open this file in window machine its not opening. On Linux machine its showing correctly . I tried many thing for that.

That is my code:-

```
      spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
      Yii::import('application.extensions.PHPWord.PHPWord',true);
      require_once('PHPWord/PHPWord.php');
      $PHPWord = new PHPWord();
      spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
      $document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate("/var/www/frontsite/agemodern/uploads/roadmaps/".$file);
      $document->setValue('Value1', 'Sun');
      $newfile='ageModern Roadmap - '.date('m-d-Y',time()).' - '.time().'.docx';

     $document = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');

     $document->save("/var/www/frontsite/agemodern/uploads/roadmaps/".$newfile);
```

and this is my phpword file code:-

```
    $zip_name=$strFilename;
    if(file_exists($zip_name))
    {

    $filename=$zip_name;

    //header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    //header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$zip_name}\"");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");  
    readfile($filename);


    //readfile($zip_name);
    // remove zip file is exists in temp path
    unlink($filename);
    }
```

Thank you in advance